# Hibernate3 with Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle12c, hibernate3

We are upgrading oracle from 11g to 12c. My application is using `hibernate3.jar` which is 3.6.8-Final version. It works great with 11g using `Oracle10gDialect` but when I connect to 12c database I get below error. I also changed classes12.jar to ojdbc7.jar.

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect to use
>   [name=Oracle, majorVersion=12]; user must register resolver or
>   explicitly set 'hibernate.dialect'

I tried downgrading till `3.1.1` and upgrading till `3.6.10-Final`. Below `3.6.8` my code wont compile as there is no Oracle10gDialect class before that. And even `3.6.10-final` version gives me same above error. I cannot upgrade to Hibernate 4. Any advise will be of great help. thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem. I use spring too and running into many issues with Spring3+Hibernate-3 (or 4)  for oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you need to explicitly declare what dialect to use. I think we did a JVM option `-Dhibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect` or we added a configuration in `domain.xml` (if you're using Glassfish) `hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`. Hope this helps.