# Hibernate and Oracle version compatibility

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g

I have a Struts-Hibernate application which is using Oracle 10g for database persistence. While running the application, sometimes at the time of execute SQL queries, I am getting an exception like:

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

I checked through google and found that it may occur due to Hibernate and Oracle (database) version mismatch.

Below are the links, but could not found proper solution:
[Hibernate 3.3.0 compatibility with Oracle 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447255/hibernate-3-3-0-compatibility-with-oracle-12c)

[Version Mismatch between Hiberate and Database](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/solved-org-hibernate-exception-genericjdbcexception-could-not-prepare-statement/)

I want to know, Is there any compatibility matrix for these two, so that we can properly understand which version we need to use:

My hibernate version is: **4.3.11 final**

My oracle version is : **10G**

below is the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

in the hibernate.cfg.xml, the Dialect is mentioned as:

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
```

Any one please suggest me the exact version matches for **Hibernate** & **Oracle**.

OR, if there is any other solution to resolve this **GenericJDBCException**, please suggest that also.

Comment: Frequently that hibernate exception has a "caused by" in the full stack trace.  Is there any other exception details for example "Caused by: "?

Comment: Yes the hibernate exception has a "Caused by" part:
_**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset**_

_at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getDate(OracleResultSetImpl.java:732)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getDate(OracleResultSet.java:410)_

_at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getDate(NewProxyResultSet.java:2988)_

Comment: Can you post some code of the data access method where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this page can help you
[java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502005/java-sql-sqlexception-exhausted-resultset)

the underlying root cause is, you are trying to loop outside of the result set (not related with dialect or the hibernate, but on the code itself). Hope it helps.